# How to use angular2 as a NPM dependency

Tags: angular

I'm using angular including from script tag like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular 2 tsconfig.json Demo</title>
    <script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.87/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
    <script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.22/angular2.dev.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <welcome></welcome>
    <script>System.import("app");</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way of avoiding script inclusion, and download my dependencies to node_modules folder with my compiled .js and typescript definition file .d.ts, include it and build it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `npm install angular2`. Check out the [quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) for more details.

You'll also need these dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    "systemjs": "0.19.22",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "0.5.15"
  },
```

then you can include them as script tags:

```
  <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```

This is the minimal working setup, you'll need `es6-shim` and `system-polyfills` for IE (and possibly some other) browsers.